# Can't loop through object list in Python

Tags: python, class, loops, python-3.x

I'm appending instances of a class to a list in Python as follows:

```
a_list = []
a_list.append(AClass())
```

(At least one append).

When trying to loop through the list:

```
for a in a_list:
    # Do something to know if loop runs...
    pass
```

It does not seem to run the loop.

When printing length of list, it's 0.

The list is attached as a property of a class* instance (whose file has file containing "AClass" imported). The list is looped through (and length checked) in a third file's class instance also attached on first-said class*'s instance.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is a ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you make sure to provide us with one? That'll not only help us, but help you as well.

Comment: >>"The list is attached as a property of a class* instance (whose file has file containing "AClass" imported). The list is looped through (and length checked) in a third file's class instance also attached on first-said class*'s instance."

Could you post more code please, 'cause what you posted so far works ok

Comment: Accepting an answer, will give you some reputation and also reward the effort of other users who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, here's what I got:

```
class AClass():
    pass

a_list = []
a_list.append(AClass())

for a in a_list:
    print(a)
# <__main__.AClass object at 0x10b510c18>

print(len(a_list))
# 1

a_list.append(AClass())

print(len(a_list))
# 2
```

Could the issue be related to your assignment of the list as a class attribute? (Would need to see your code to confirm.)

Answer (score 1):

hmm ... works for me:

```
>>> class AClass(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.a = "AClass"
... 
>>> a_list = []
>>> a_list.append(AClass())
>>> a_list.append(AClass())
>>> a_list.append(AClass())
>>> for a in a_list:
...   print a.a
... 
AClass
AClass
AClass
>>>
```

Using python 2.7